# changing notification icon color in image asset in android studio

Tags: android, android-assets, android-assetmanager

[image]

how can I change the color of notification icon in image asset? I wanted to use an icon from image asset to use as notification icon but I am finding no option as fill color(to change the color) to my latest android studio version, isn't it possible now? I also tried notification icon generator GitHub link-

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=clipart&source.clipart=notifications&source.space.trim=0&source.space.pad=-0.1&name=ic_stat_notifications

Comment: It's because they should be black or white and the system will colour them accordingly

Answer (score 2):

use vector assets instead of image asset. 
go to **res->new->vector assets**

or else you can import svg icon with same process.